# How to get Google Drive API response in Python when using Batch requests?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

So I am using Google Drive API to extract metadata from a drive folder, and then storing that data in a csv file. I need to use Batch processing for getting data from multiple files but, how i cannot understand how using the `batch` method.
This is the code I am using right now.

```
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(q = f"parents = '{drive_folder_id}'", pageSize=20,
                                   fields=drive_data_fields).execute()

    # gets 4 responses: kind, nextPageToken,files,incompleteSearch
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
        return
    print('Files:')
    df = pd.DataFrame(items)
    df.to_csv(drive_data_file)
```

the `service.files().list(q = f"parents = '{drive_folder_id}'", pageSize=5, fields=drive_data_fields)` returns the metadata of files in folder of drive. What I need is somehow send this as a batch request which returns the metadata as well. However batch.add does not give a response, result returns None.

This is how I want to use the code

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Call the Drive v3 API
batch = service.new_batch_http_request()
batch.add(service.files().list(q = f"parents = '{drive_folder_id}'", pageSize=5, fields=drive_data_fields))
result = batch.execute()
#above should return a response that I can write to a csv file.
```

Problem is, that I have to get the data so that I can write it, but here `result` returns `None`, and can't understand how batches `response` works.

Read the docs, but couldn't get an answer, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal. In your showing script, it seems that you want to use `service.files().list(q = f"parents = '{drive_folder_id}'", pageSize=5, fields=drive_data_fields)` as the batch requests. In this case, I cannot understand your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike so the `service.files().list(q = f"parents = '{drive_folder_id}'", pageSize=5, fields=drive_data_fields)` returns the metadata of files in folder of drive. 
What I need is somehow send this as a batch request which returns the metadata as well. However `batch.add` does not give a response, `result` returns `None`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

When using batch you can access to response with callback function.

Define a callback function that print the response :

```
def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    print('response is '+ str(response))
```

and then use it during batch creation :

```
batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
```